# Flexbox layout resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am playing around with resizing flexbox elements on web page.

[image]

Thus far I am able to resize the "terminal" and "output" boxes, left,right and content still needs to be done, but I am seriously rethinking my implementation.

The issue I have with my implementation is that it is not generic enough, and I am going to have to write function for every resize handle. It will also mean that if I ever change the layout I will have to redo the resize handling.

Seeing though this is still early days of the app, I just know the layout will change.

Does anyone know of a better way to handle resizing of flexboxes.

Please note, I am not using jquery, and i would like to continue using pure javascript.

jsfiddle example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stoic/Lvc6amg3/35/)

```js
var resizer = document.getElementById('debug-resize');
var debugWrapper = document.getElementById('debug');
var terminal = document.getElementById('debug-terminal');
var output = document.getElementById('debug-output');
var isHandlerDragging = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  if (e.target === resizer) {
    isHandlerDragging = true;
  }
});


document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (!isHandlerDragging) {
    return false;
  }

  var OffsetLeft = debugWrapper.offsetLeft;
  var ponterRelX = e.clientX - OffsetLeft;

  terminal.style.width = (ponterRelX) + 'px';
  terminal.style.flexGrow = 0;
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  isHandlerDragging = false;
});
```

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  }
  body {
   display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  footer{
   margin: 0;
    background-color:red;
  }
  header{
  height:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
  }
  main{
    display: flex;
   flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color:red;
  }
  
  #left-side{
   background-color:orange;
    width:100px;
  }
  
  #right-side{
   background-color:orange;
    width:100px;
  }
  
  #window{
   height:30px;
    background-color:green;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #content-wrapper{
    background-color:blue;
   flex:1;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
  }
  
  #process-canvas-wrapper{
   flex:1;
    background-color:blue;
  }
  
  #debug{
    display: flex;
    color:#fff;
   min-height:100px;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  #debug-output{
   flex:1;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:grey;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
  #debug-terminal{
   flex:1;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
  
  #icon{ width:20px;}
  #file-menu{flex:1}
  #toolbox{display:flex;width:150px;justify-content: flex-end;}
  
  #left-resize{
   width:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    cursor: ew-resize;
  }
  
  #right-resize{
   width:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    cursor: ew-resize;
  }
  
  #content-resize{
   height:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    cursor: ns-resize;
  }
  
  #debug-resize{
   width:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
    cursor: ew-resize;
  }
  
  #resizeV{
   height:10px;
    background-color:#fff
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Example</title>
<body>
  <section id="window">
    <div id="icon">X</div>
    <div id="file-menu">file</div>
    <div id="toolbox">close</div>
  </section>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>
    <aside id="left-side">left</aside>
    <div id="left-resize" class"panel-resize">.</div>
    <section id="content-wrapper">
      <section id="process-canvas-wrapper">content</section>
      <div id="content-resize" class"panel-resize">.</div>
      <section id="debug">
        <section id="debug-terminal">terminal</section>
        <div id="debug-resize" class"panel-resize">.</div>
        <section id="debug-output">output</section>
      </section>
    </section>
    <div id="right-resize" class"panel-resize">.</div>
    <aside id="right-side">right</aside>
  </main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/stoic/d6h7q19x/30/ using https://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/  lib:

Comment: You could take a look at CSS grid instead. CSS grid would be perfect for this usecase